# how to include views in asp.net 5 class library nuget package

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating a class library project that will contain some ViewComponents.
It is nice that VS 2015 can automatically produce the NuGet package for me, but is there any way that I can make it include content files like .cshtml view files that my ViewComponents will need?

Previously I've done packaging with batch files and nuspec files to make it include content, will I have to continue that approach or is there a way to tell VS 2015 about content files to include?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not doable as yet. The feature will be in beta7

Comment: I believe one possible way to achieve this currently is to have your files embedded as resources and then have a composite file provider in your main application which can look at either embedded or physical file system for files. You would set this composite provider on StaticFiles middleware as well as RazorViewEngineOptions.

Comment: @davidfowl now that beta7 is out can you elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: The feature made it into beta8

Comment: beta8 is out now and this is supposed to be possible but I cannot get it to work. I add this in my project.json "content": [ "Views/Shared/*.cshtml", "Views/Shared/Components/Navigation/*.cshtml" ], but when I inspect the contents of the generated .nupkg file it does not contain the files. I tried also listing individual files with contentFiles but that also did not work. Any info on how to do this?

Comment: ok, I learned from the beta8 announcement that I need to use pakInclude and that worked as far as including the files in the package. But when I created a local nuget feed to test it and pulled in the package to a web app, it did not install the content files into the web app. I tried also using the "content" in project.json thinking maybe it needs that in addition to pakInclude.  What am I missing? The whole goal of including the content files is to deliver them into a web app project. ie Views that are used by my viewcomponent so that the consuming app also gets the needed views.

Comment: @davidfowl is there any update on this? I also would like to place my Views into the class library so I can share it across the websites as a feature. Thank you.

Comment: I read about it here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/15/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8.aspx so it is currently possible to include files in the package but they do not currently get installed into the consuming app, nuget just ignores the files. I "think" this is supposed to be fixed later.

Comment: @davidfowl rc2 is here now and it seems I still cannot get a view delivered from nuget, I really hope I'm missing something and wish someone could provide an update on whether this is supposed to be possible and if not why, this is a major blocker for me if it can't be done https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1490

Comment: for others reading this, afaik it is not currently possible in rc2 to deliver views from nuget, but for my needs using embedded views with the option for the user to opt out of using embedded views and download them into their own project has turned out to be a good solution https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1490

Comment: Any insights now on how to accomplish that?