# How distribute views from nuget package

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core

I have dnx project that produces a nuget package.

Along with binaries i'd like to distribute razor views.

Is there any way to achieve this.

### Edit

As @davidfowl [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412210/how-to-include-views-in-asp-net-5-class-library-nuget-package#comment52673569_31424448) the feature is now supported in beta8.

I'm using 1.0.0-rc1-final version.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to include views in asp.net 5 class library nuget package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412210/how-to-include-views-in-asp-net-5-class-library-nuget-package)