# Create HTML Custom Control in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create a custom nav-bar for all my web apps, this nav-bar must call a RESTful API to retrieve some info from a DB (it's the same DB and info for all my apps), I know using Html Helpers could create this component, but I also know that I can't create a HTML helper with business logic.

How can I create this component?

Comment: can't you pass the menu links via view model and get the same in custom html helper class?

Comment: @Deepu I will not load menu links, I want to retrieve info of the logged user.

Answer (score 0):

Break your HTML into partial views, make JSON calls to your actions to make them gather your data and render it with your related partial view, append rendered HTML's to your nav-bar.

Comment: Can I create a nuget package with those partial views and share it as a nuget reference to others projects?

Comment: I don't have enough information about nuget packaging, sorry.

edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412210/how-to-include-views-in-asp-net-5-class-library-nuget-package